# Concerning the tangent space of an exotic $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

My geometric intuition is very poor, so my naive approach to this question is "if $M$ is an exotic $\mathbb R^4$, then $TM$ must be something like $\mathbb R^8$, which is not exotic". Of course, my statement "like $\mathbb R^8$ " is probably rubbish.

So, my concrete question is: is the tangent space of an exotic $\mathbb R^4$ a "nice" manifold? I personally don't consider exotic manifolds "nice" (again, because of my poor geometric intuition, though certainly they are very respectable objects of study). I am open-minded about what manifolds a topologist would regard as "nice".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An exotic $\Bbb R^4$ (let us denote it by $\Sigma$) is homeomorphic to the usual $\Bbb R^4$, so $\Sigma$ is contractible. Any vector bundle over a contractible manifold is trivial, and hence the tangent bundle $T\Sigma$ is trivial: $T\Sigma \cong \Sigma \times \Bbb R^4$. Hence we have that $T\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^8$. Since it is known that there are no exotic $\Bbb R^n$'s for $n \neq 4$, it follows that $T\Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^8$ for any exotic $\Bbb R^4$ $\Sigma$.

Comment: Is this argument valid over not compact manifolds like $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @levitopher Isomorphism classes of rank $k$ vector bundles over a paracompact, Hausdorff topological space $X$ are classified by homotopy classes of maps $[X, BO(k)]$. When $X$ is paracompact, Hausdorff, and contractible this implies that the only vector bundle over $X$ is the trivial bundle. Manifolds are paracompact and Hausdorff topological spaces, so we can apply the argument (even in the noncompact case).